# Disabling touch wrapper in Alexa Presentation Language

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-presentation-language

I am having a problem with using the touch wrapper in APL, at the moment when the user touches the screen - it will completely pause the skill.

I am using this reference: [apl touch wrapper doc](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-touchwrapper.html)

I have tried the following syntax in my json file with no success:

```
{
    "type": "APL",
    "version": "1.0",
    "imports": [
        {
            "name": "alexa-layouts",
            "version": "1.0.0"
        }
    ],
    "layouts": {},
    "mainTemplate": {
        "parameters": [
            "payload"
        ],
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "TouchWrapper",
                "height":"100vh",
                "width":"100vw",
                "disabled":"true",
                "item": {
                    "type": "Text",
                    "id":"testing",
                    "text": "testing disabled touch wrapper",
                    "color": "#66DFFF",
                    "fontSize": 30
                }

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

the "disabled" property doesnt seem to work, i have successfully implemented the onpress send event command, so i could find a work around this way, but it would be much better if the disabled property just worked!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can enable and disable via the touch wrapper the SetState command:

```
{
  "type": "SetState",
  "componentId": "your_touch_wrapper_id",
  "state": "disabled",
  "value": true
}
```

In APL 1.1 we have added a new section to the APL doc called [onMount](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-document.html#apl_document_on_mount_property) that you can use to send commands right away. You can try to send the command above in onMount to see if that works.